# Python Sentiment Analysis : IndexError - list index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to compile a program for detecting sentiment analysis. However, I am really new with Python and this is the first time I'm dealing with it. Whenever I compile the source 
code, the following error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment.py", line 23, in <module>
    tweets.append( [row[3], row[4]] );
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The line 23 is

```
for row in reader:
    tweets.append( [row[3], row[4]] );
```

And this is the source code

```
"""
@package sentiment
Twitter sentiment analysis.

This code performs sentiment analysis on Tweets.

A custom feature extractor looks for key words and emoticons.  These are fed in
to a naive Bayes classifier to assign a label of 'positive', 'negative', or
'neutral'.  Optionally, a principle components transform (PCT) is used to lessen
the influence of covariant features.

"""
import csv, random
import nltk
import tweet_features, tweet_pca


# read all tweets and labels
fp = open( 'sentiment.csv', 'rb' )
reader = csv.reader( fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\' )
tweets = []
for row in reader:
    tweets.append( [row[3], row[4]] );

# treat neutral and irrelevant the same
for t in tweets:
    if t[1] == 'irrelevant':
        t[1] = 'neutral'


# split in to training and test sets
random.shuffle( tweets );

fvecs = [(tweet_features.make_tweet_dict(t),s) for (t,s) in tweets]
v_train = fvecs[:2500]
v_test  = fvecs[2500:]


# dump tweets which our feature selector found nothing
#for i in range(0,len(tweets)):
#    if tweet_features.is_zero_dict( fvecs[i][0] ):
#        print tweets[i][1] + ': ' + tweets[i][0]


# apply PCA reduction
#(v_train, v_test) = \
#        tweet_pca.tweet_pca_reduce( v_train, v_test, output_dim=1.0 )


# train classifier
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(v_train);
#classifier = nltk.classify.maxent.train_maxent_classifier_with_gis(v_train);


# classify and dump results for interpretation
print '\nAccuracy %f\n' % nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, v_test)
#print classifier.show_most_informative_features(200)


# build confusion matrix over test set
test_truth   = [s for (t,s) in v_test]
test_predict = [classifier.classify(t) for (t,s) in v_test]

print 'Confusion Matrix'
print nltk.ConfusionMatrix( test_truth, test_predict )
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you post sample of sentiment.csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line 23,

```
for row in reader:
    tweets.append( [row[3], row[4]] );
```

`append` method in list inserts an element to the list. So, the syntax is incorrect in that line. You can append one element at a time as:

```
for row in reader:
    tweets.append([row[3])
    tweets.append([row[4])
```

Comment: You don't end lines with semicolon in Python.

Comment: @SudipKafle yeah... that was error in the code in question